# Issues formatting numbers in Access from SQL Server query

Tags: sql, ms-access, formatting, sql-view

I have a production database that uses a SQL server back end with tables linked to an Access front end. For performance reasons, I am trying to write most of my report queries as SQL views and simply passing parameters in from Access.

The problem I'm running into though is that I don't seem to be allowed to format fields that were calculated in the SQL view.

For example, I have a table:

```
CaseLot    Drums    GrossWeight    %H2O
   01        10       10,301       5.21
```

Drums, GrossWeight, and Drums are all decimal data types but each have varying scale.

In my view I include the values from the above table, but also the following calculated fields:

```
[GrossWeight] - 19.6*[Drums] AS NetWeight
([GrossWeight] -19.6*[Drums])*(100-[%H2O])/100 AS DryWeight
```

When I pull these calculated fields through to Access, I have no issue formatting the NetWeight field, but it won't let me for the DryWeight field. It is really frustrating, because I would like to display the DryWeight field to only two decimal places and it won't do it.

I have also tried applying the Round() function in Access, but it seems to give me a "circular reference" error when I include a scale to round to. Round(DryWeight) works to round it to 0 decimal places, but Round(DryWeight,2) give me an error.

What is happening here?

Comment: What does the code for dry weight you showed produce when you run it?  Also, can you select %H2O at all?  Maybe the problem is the column name starting with a special character.

Comment: It produces 9578.5295 for the example given. I would like to display is as 9,578.53. I don't have any trouble selecting the %H2O. I have more complicated summation queries built that also work just fine, except for this random formatting issue.

Comment: Did you try the format function mentioned here?  http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/format.php

Comment: Progress! When I include the Format() function in the Access query it works. Is there a reason that the "Format" drop down list in the properties tab for these calculated values is blank though?

Comment: Its almost as if Access is recognizing these calculated numbers as strings.

Comment: In the SQL Server database, what is the column specification for [%H2O]? That is, if it is `Decimal(m,n)` what are the values for `m` and `n`?

Comment: Gord, Decimal data types for [%H2O] = (18,3), [Drums] = (18,0), [GrossWeight] = (18,1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Its almost as if Access is recognizing these calculated numbers as strings.

It is. I recreated the issue using SQL Server 2005 and Access 2010. I have a View in SQL Server named [CaseLotView] ...

```sql
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CaseLotView]
AS
SELECT
    CaseLot, 
    Drums, 
    GrossWeight, 
    [%H2O], 
    GrossWeight - 19.6 * Drums AS NetWeight, 
    (GrossWeight - 19.6 * Drums) * (100 - [%H2O]) / 100 AS DryWeight
FROM
    dbo.CaseLotData
```

...and when I create a linked table in Access and open it I see the following:

[image: AccessView.png]

Notice that the [NetWeight] value is right-aligned (interpreted as numeric) while the [DryWeight] value is left-aligned (interpreted as string).

One workaround would be to create an Access query based on the linked table that converts [DryWeight] to numeric using the `CDbl()` function:

```sql
SELECT 
    dbo_CaseLotView.CaseLot, 
    dbo_CaseLotView.NetWeight, 
    CDbl([DryWeight]) AS dblDryWeight
FROM dbo_CaseLotView;
```

Reports based on that query will recognize [dblDryWeight] as numeric and offer the expected formatting options.

(Note that while there is a `CDec()` function in VBA it does not work in Access queries - ref: [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225931).)

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! Is there a reason this is happening? Why would Access interpret it as a string?

Comment: @bmansk8s I can't offer a specific reason, but sometimes Access will treat numeric results as string if **(1)** the resulting data type is one that Access doesn't directly support, or **(2)** if there is some type juggling involved (as in this case where it looks like the SQL Server View is actually returning a Float instead of a Decimal, based on the number of decimal places that are displayed).